# Marshalling structure with const char* in unmanaged code returns 'System.AccessViolationException'

Tags: c#, c++, c, marshalling

In C# the structure with string member is as below:
  public struct EDNetBuf
    {

```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]

    public string dummy;

    public delegate void finalizeDelegate(System.IntPtr @object);
    public finalizeDelegate finalize;


    public readonly int _ref;
    public EDNetEventType type;

    public uint len;


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string data;

}
```

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]

```
 public struct EDNetFrame
{
    public EDNetBuf buf; //*< a buffer, the base object

    public uint timestamp; //*< timestamp
    public byte channel; //*< channel number
    public byte ptype; //*< payload, see #EDNetCodecID
    public ushort flags; //*< flags, see Flag

    public int fmt; //*< format, see #EDNetFrameFormat
    public int width; //*< The width of video frame
    public int height; //*< The height of video frame
}
```

I am having unmanaged c code from which I converted C# code as follows:

```
struct EDNetBuf
{
  /**
   * private data. NEVER MODIFY THIS!
   */

  const char *dummy;
  /**
   * private data. NEVER MODIFY THIS!
   */
  void (*finalize) (void *object);
  /**
   * private data. NEVER MODIFY THIS!
   */
  int _ref;
  /**
   * the length of buffer data.
   */
  unsigned int len;

  /**
   * the pointer to buffer data.
   */
  char *data;
};
```

In C# When i marshal this using:

f = (EDNetFrame)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(param,typeof(EDNetFrame));

When marshalling as above with PtrToStructure,I am getting error An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt..'

I found out this is because of the structure member string dummy. How to solve this error ?

Comment: The *data* member is not very likely to be a string.  You wouldn't need a *len* member if *data* was actually a string.  Get ahead by declaring them both as IntPtr.  Review the *type* member, doesn't appear in the C declaration.  We can't see the [DllImport] declarations, forgetting CallingConvention is another way to easily trip an AVE.

Comment: @Hans Passant After changing both dummy and data members as Inptr and removing the type member from the decleration it works now. Thanks for your help.